# Setting conditions for music selection

Tags: java, android, if-statement, conditional-statements, playback

I want to set conditions for my apps music selection. I have two different playlists, and to call them i use the function `playLTsongs(0)` and `playHTsongs(0)`, [0 = index of song in the songlist i.e play first song].

Basic but this is what im looking for:

```
if(HRate < 100){
    mp.play(playLTSongs(0));
    mp.pause(playHTsong(0));  
}
else if (HRate > 100){
    mp.pause(playLTSong(0));
    mp.play(playHTsong(0));   
}
```

I know this is rough, and it may not be possible having conditions in the `mp.pause/play()`, another way may be using case statements? if anyone can help please?

Comment: How does this not work?

Comment: I want it to loop through this condition continuosly

Comment: So you would need to have some sort of event that fires whenever you get an updated value for `HRate`.  That event would contain this code.  How and when does the `HRate` value change?

Comment: to Explain, I am using a HRM with built in bluetooth which is communicating with my app, the heart rate is sent per/second, im almost sure it is coming in as a 'Byte' ?

Comment: so you have some sort of loop running on a background thread reading from your bluetooth stream.  When  you get another value from the stream you need to check that value and do what you want.  The question doesnt say anything about what you want or what you've tried.   You should update your question with a more specific question and more source code.